# Choosing Specific instances for scaling in and scaling out in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

Using Auto Scaling with Load balance in AWS, We can do the following things, according to my understanding:

1. we can scale up and scale down according to load.
2. all instances have the same image.

But I have a different problem:

1. if we have less load then we should terminate a big machine and start a small machine and vice versa.
2. small machine and the big machine has a different image

but I am not getting any help from AWS UI.

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling can **launch new instances** and can **terminate instances**. It only ever adds or removes instances -- it never changes the size of an instance. This is why you'll often see it referred to as "scale-out and scale-in" rather than "scale-up and scale-down".

When a scaling policy is triggered and Auto Scaling needs to launch a new instance, it uses the provided **Launch Configuration** or **Launch Template** to determine what type of instance to launch, which network to use, etc.

Therefore, an Auto Scaling group typically consists of **all the same size instances** since they are all launched from the same Launch Configuration. This is actually a good thing because it makes it easier for the scaling alarms to know when to add/remove instances and it also helps Load Balancers distribute load amongst instances since they assume that all instances are sized the same.

So, rather than "terminate a big machine and start a small machine and vice versa", Auto Scaling simply **launches the same sized instance or terminates an instance**.

Also, all instances should use the same AMI since load balancers will send traffic to every instance, **expecting them to behave the same way**.

You could, if you wish, modify the Launch Configuration associated with the Auto Scaling group so that, when it next launches an instance, it launches a different-sized instance. However, Auto Scaling and Load Balancers will not 'know' that it is a different-sized instance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically John answered this question.
As alternative we can have some sophisticated scaling logic in any computing resource. For example AWS Alarms can send SNS notification, that Lambda reads and scale in or out using sophisticated logic you have (big or small instances etc.).